# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when creating dynamic DataFrame on Spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

My goal is to create a dataframe dynamically from columns and values from an external dataframe. This is how the dataframe is created with manual schema and data definitions:

```
val columnSufix: String = "isNull" 

val data = Seq(Row(
                   details.filter(col("DAY").isNull).count(),
                   details.filter(col("CHANNEL_CATEGORY").isNull).count(),
                   details.filter(col("SOURCE").isNull).count(),
                   details.filter(col("PLATFORM").isNull).count()
              )
            )

val schema: StructType = new StructType()
  .add(s"DAY_$columnSufix", LongType)
  .add(s"CHANNEL_CATEGORY_$columnSufix", LongType)
  .add(s"SOURCE_$columnSufix", LongType)
  .add(s"PLATFORM_$columnSufix", LongType)


val testDf: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)


testDf.show(false)
```

The output when I execute the above script is the following:

```
columnSufix: String = isNull
data: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = List([0,0,0,83845])
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(DAY_isNull,LongType,true),StructField(CHANNEL_CATEGORY_isNull,LongType,true),StructField(SOURCE_isNull,LongType,true),StructField(PLATFORM_isNull,LongType,true))
testDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [DAY_isNull: bigint, CHANNEL_CATEGORY_isNull: bigint ... 2 more fields]
```

So far so good. The problem is when I use the below script that makes the creation of the DataFrame more dynamic, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error:

```
val cols = details.columns.toSeq.take(4)
val columnSuffix: String = "ISNULL" 

val data = cols.map(column => Row(details.filter(col(column).isNull).count())).toList

val schema = StructType(cols.map(column => StructField(column + s"_$columnSuffix", LongType)))

val testDf: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)

testDf.show(false)
```

The output when I compiled the above script is similar as the manual dataFrame creation, with the exception that when I run testDf.show(false), it gives me this error:

```
Caused by: RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, DAY_ISNULL), LongType, false) AS DAY_ISNULL#243076L
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, CHANNEL_CATEGORY_ISNULL), LongType, false) AS CHANNEL_CATEGORY_ISNULL#243077L
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 2, SOURCE_ISNULL), LongType, false) AS SOURCE_ISNULL#243078L
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 3, PLATFORM_ISNULL), LongType, false) AS PLATFORM_ISNULL#243079L
Caused by: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
```

What's this happening? My feeling is that somehow Spark is not sending the values of `details.filter(col(column).isNull).count())` straight to the invocation of `createDataFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, for each column, you're instantiating a row object:

```scala
val data = cols.map(column => Row(details.filter(col(column).isNull).count())).toList
```

So at the end, you'll have:

```
Seq(
  Row(0),
  Row(0),
  Row(0),
  Row(83845)
)
// so calling .toDF will expect 1 column name
```

But you're supplying 4 column names, what you intended to do is this:

```
Seq(Row(0, 0, 0, 83845)) // notice the single row, with 4 columns instead
```

What you need to do is:

```scala
val data: Seq[Long] = cols.map(column => details.filter(col(column).isNull).count())
// Now you have your values here (Seq(0, 0, 0, 83845))
```

The tricky part here is to convert `Seq` to `Product` (Tuples). This depends on how you want to manage it. You can use shapeless, or reflection to do this. Or if you're sure about the number of columns, I recommend this:

```scala
val tupled = data.toList match {
  case a :: b :: c :: d :: Nil => (a, b, c, d)
}
```

At the end:

```scala
Seq(tupled).toDF(cols: _*)
```

You can also address your issue using spark APIs. I suggested the above approach because you seemed to prefer Scala-ish approach. If you need spark APIs, let me know, I'll update the answer.

---

### Update

So let's continue where we left on `data` variable instead.

```
Seq(Row(0), Row(0), Row(0), Row(8723))
```

We want to retrieve a single row with 4 columns instead of 4 rows with 1 column each.

```scala
//                       ++ is union-ing rows,  : _* is passing seq as vararg
val row = Row(data.map(_.toSeq).reduce(_ ++ _): _*)
```

Now let's create dataframe with the given row:

```scala
val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(row)), schema)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I removed .toList based on your recommandation and it gives this `ArrayBuffer([0], [0], [0], [18])` instead. 

You mentioned that you know how to do it with Spark APIs. Would be possible for you to add it in the answer please?

Comment: @ultraInstinct you're welcome, but I didn't mention to remove the `.toList`. Sure, I'll attempt to do it today.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is in pyspark

you can try to do same in scala spark as well.

First reduce is present only in python you can find the same functionality in scala I guess fold does the same .

code goes here

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,LongType,Row
from functools import reduce
data=[(32609,878,199),
      (32609,878,199),
    (32609,832,199),
    (45470,231,199),
    (45470,231,199),
    (45470,231,199),
    (42482,1001,299),
    (42482,16,291)]
df1=spark.createDataFrame(data_with_null_examples,["DAY","CHANNEL_CATEGORY","SOURCE"])
details=df1.withColumn("PLATFORM",F.lit(None))
dyn_columns_list_org=["DAY","CHANNEL_CATEGORY","SOURCE","PLATFORM"]
dynamic_data = Row(*list(map(lambda x:details.filter(F.col(x).isNull()).count(),dyn_columns_list_org)))
print(dynamic_data)
schema = StructType()
dynamic_schema =  reduce(lambda x,y:x.add(y+"_isNull",data_type=LongType()),dyn_columns_list_org,schema)
print(dynamic_schema)
dyn_df = spark.createDataFrame([dynamic_data],schema=dynamic_schema)
dyn_df.show(10,0)
```

```
output :-

    +----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+
    |DAY_isNull|CHANNEL_CATEGORY_isNull|SOURCE_isNull|PLATFORM_isNull|
    +----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+
    |0         |0                      |0            |8              |
     +----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+

Kindly upvote if you like my solution.
```